# Able to display the result of a promise but length of the result appears as undefined

Tags: vue.js, promise

I'm new to vue/promise and I am struggling to understand why when I try to display the result of a promise I end up with the expected data but when I try to find out its length, it says `undefined`

When I try to display the alerts from `displayAlerts()` , I can see a list of alerts, 2 in total. However in `computed` within the `title` function `${this.displayAlerts.length}` appears as `undefined`, I was expecting to see `2`.

Does it have something to do with `displayAlerts()` resulting in a promise? How do I fix the code such that I get `2` instead of `undefined`?

The code is below:

```
<template>
 <div>
 {{displayAlerts}}
  <li v-for="alert in alerts" class="alert">
     {{alert['name']}}
  </li>
 </div>
</template>

export default {

  data () {
    return {
      alerts: null,
      alert: new Alert(), 
      updatedAlert: new Alert(),
      deletedAlert: new Alert(),
    };
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("authentication",['token']),
    ...mapGetters("user",['profile']),
    displayAlerts() {
      return getUserAlert({
        user_id: this.profile.user_id,
        token: this.token
      }).then(response => (this.alerts = response.data)).catch(
        error => console.log(error)
      )
    },
    title () {
      return `My Alerts (${this.displayAlerts.length})`
    },
    test2() {
      return [1,2,3]
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: `this.displayAlerts` appears to be Function. If so, then it will not have a length property. I would guess that you want the length property of the object delivered by the Promise returned by `this.displayAlerts()`.
Try something like `async title () { return `My Alerts (${(await this.displayAlerts()).length })` };`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 In Vue, a function declared in the `computed` section will be mapped to a property. So `this.displayAlerts` will be the promise. `title` is also a computed property and while you could technically make it an `async` function that generally wouldn't be practical given how they are typically used.

Comment: @skirtle, now I understand ..... it's black magic :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
<template>
 <div v-if="alerts">
  <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
  <li v-for="alert in alerts" class="alert">
     {{ alert.name }}
  </li>
 </div>
</template>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      alerts: null
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('authentication', ['token']),
    ...mapGetters('user', ['profile']),

    title () {
      // Handle the null case
      const alerts = this.alerts || []

      return `My Alerts (${alerts.length})`
    }
  },

  methods: {
    // This needs to be in the methods, not a computed property
    displayAlerts () {
      return getUserAlert({
        user_id: this.profile.user_id,
        token: this.token
      }).then(response => (this.alerts = response.data)).catch(
        error => console.log(error)
      )
    }
  },

  // Initiate loading in a hook, not via the template
  created () {
    this.displayAlerts()
  }
}
</script>
```

Notes:

1. Computed properties shouldn't have side-effects. Anything asynchronous falls into that category. I've moved `displayAlerts` to a method instead.
2. Templates shouldn't have side-effects. The call to load the data should be in a hook such as `created` or `mounted` instead.
3. `title` needs to access `this.alerts` rather than trying to manipulate the promise.
4. While the data is loading the value of `alerts` will be `null`. You need to handle that in some way. I've included a `v-if` in the template and some extra handling in `title`. You may choose to handle it differently.
5. I've added `title` to the template but that's just for demonstration purposes. You can, of course, do whatever you want with it.
6. I've assumed that your original `displayAlerts` function was working correctly and successfully populates `alerts`. You may want to rename it to something more appropriate, like `loadAlerts`.

Comment: Thank you @skirtle. This is extremely helpful